# sequelize.js addIndex not using indexName

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to create an index using sequelize.js addIndex function, the index is created but not with the name specified in the indexName option.

I am using the code below

```
  queryInterface.addIndex('Item',
  ['name', 'description'], {
    indicesType: 'FULLTEXT',
    indexName: 'idx_item_fulltext'
  })
```

After running migration, the index is created with the name 'item_name_description' and not 'idx_item_fulltext' which is the name I specified.

Comment: I guess `indicesType` does not work as well

Comment: Could you paste `Seqeulize` version you're using?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For `sequelize-cli` and `sequelize` version `5+` there are no `indicesType` and `indexName` properties in [addIndex](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/dialects/abstract/query-interface.js%7EQueryInterface.html#instance-method-addIndex) options:

Please try:

```js
queryInterface.addIndex('Item', ['name', 'description'], {
    type: 'FULLTEXT',
    name: 'idx_item_fulltext'
})
```